# Rotas chamando a mesma action do controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rotas, chave-composta

Olá, estou com o seguinte problema:

estou criando um sistema de locação de filmes em um trabalho da faculdade, onde o usuário pode locar filmes de diferentes locadoras.

O primeiro problema que estou tendo com rotas, é que um usuário pode adicionar filmes aos favoritos, então tentei criar a rota desse jeito:

```
  resources :usuarios do
    resources :filmes
  end
```

que gerou as rotas:

```
    usuario_filmes GET    /usuarios/:usuario_id/filmes(.:format)      filmes#index
           POST   /usuarios/:usuario_id/filmes(.:format)      filmes#create
new_usuario_filme  GET    /usuarios/:usuario_id/filmes/new(.:format)  filmes#new
edit_usuario_filme GET    /usuarios/:usuario_id/filmes/:id/edit(.:format)      filmes#edit
    usuario_filme  GET    /usuarios/:usuario_id/filmes/:id(.:format)  filmes#show
           PATCH  /usuarios/:usuario_id/filmes/:id(.:format)  filmes#update
           PUT    /usuarios/:usuario_id/filmes/:id(.:format)  filmes#update
               DELETE /usuarios/:usuario_id/filmes/:id(.:format)  filmes#destroy
```

O problema é que essas rotas esão chamando as mesmas *actions* que eu uso para criar um novo filme. Minha dúvida é como faz pra especificar as *actions* que deverão ser chamadas dentro do *controller*.

Um outro problema que estou tendo é com a tabela `preco` que se refere ao valor da locação e a chave dessa tabela é composta: `locadora_id` e `filme_id`. Como eu crio rotas para cadastrar um novo preco? Estou tentando da seguinte forma:

```
  match 'precos/new/:filme_id', controller: 'precos', action: 'new', via: 'get'
```

Onde, na view, o usuário informa o id da locadora. Mas essa rota sempre chama o método show e entende que o new é o parâmetro locadora_id, porque o método show é definido assim:

```
precos/:locadora_id/:filme_id
```

Gostaria muito que me ajudassem a entender melhor como funciona as rotas no rails.

Os modelos:

```
class Preco < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :filme
    belongs_to :locadora
end

class Filme < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :usuarios
    has_many :precos, dependent: :destroy
end

class Locadora < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :usuarios
    has_many :precos, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seu problema esteja no relacionamento.
Você preicsa cria um controller e resources para uma tabela associativa.

**Exemplo:**

```
class Favoritos < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :usuaio
  has_many :filme
end
```

Se quiser pode criá-lo através de um `scaffold`.

Esse relacionamento é necessário para tratar a informação através das rotas.
Pois elas normalmente inserem somente em uma tabela.

Já a questão do preço pode ser resolvida com o `resource`.
Indenpendente se é coposto ou não, basta fazer os `selects` na `view`, ou se achar melhor, pode usar o `accepts_nested_attributes_for` na modelo e cadastrar mais de uma tabela utilizando essa linha.

**Exemplo particular:**

## MODEL aluno

```
class Aluno < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :pessoa, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pessoa
end

    ##CONTROLLER aluno
    
        class AlunosController < ApplicationController
          before_action :set_aluno, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
        
          # GET /alunos
          # GET /alunos.json
          def index
            @alunos = Aluno.all
          end
        
          # GET /alunos/1
          # GET /alunos/1.json
          def show
          end
        
          # GET /alunos/new
          def new
            @aluno = Aluno.new
            @aluno.build_pessoa
          end
        
          # GET /alunos/1/edit
          def edit
          end
        
          # POST /alunos
          # POST /alunos.json
          def create
            @aluno = Aluno.new(aluno_params)
            respond_to do |format|
              if @aluno.save
                format.html { redirect_to @aluno, notice: 'Aluno was successfully created.' }
                format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @aluno }
              else
                format.html { render :new }
                format.json { render json: @aluno.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
              end
            end
          end
        
          # PATCH/PUT /alunos/1
          # PATCH/PUT /alunos/1.json
          def update
            respond_to do |format|
              if @aluno.update(aluno_params)
                format.html { redirect_to @aluno, notice: 'Aluno was successfully updated.' }
                format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @aluno }
              else
                format.html { render :edit }
                format.json { render json: @aluno.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
              end
            end
          end
        
          # DELETE /alunos/1
          # DELETE /alunos/1.json
          def destroy
            @aluno.destroy
            respond_to do |format|
              format.html { redirect_to alunos_url, notice: 'Aluno was successfully destroyed.' }
              format.json { head :no_content }
            end
          end
        
          private
            # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
            def set_aluno
              @aluno = Aluno.find(params[:id])
            end
        
            # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
            def aluno_params
              params.require(:aluno).permit(:pessoa_id, :ativo, :matricula, pessoa_attributes: [:nome, :rua, :bairro, :sexo, :telefone, :email])
            end
        end

    #VIEW _form aluno
    <%= form_with(model: aluno, local: true) do |form| %>
      <% if aluno.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(aluno.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this aluno from being saved:</h2>
    
          <ul>
          <% aluno.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

<%= form.fields_for :pessoa do |form| %>
<div class="container">
  <div class="formulario">
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label "Nome:" %> 
    <br><%= form.text_field :nome, id: :pessoa_nome, :placeholder => "Nome Completo", :size => "60" %>
  </div>
  
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label "Rua: " %>
    <br><%= form.text_field :rua, id: :pessoa_rua, :size => "60" %>
  </div>

   <div class="field">
    <%= form.label "Bairro: " %>
    <br><%= form.text_field :bairro, id: :pessoa_bairro, :size => "60"%>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label "Sexo: " %>
    <br><%= form.select :sexo, ['Masculino', 'Feminino'] %><br>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label "Telefone: " %>
    <br><%= form.number_field :telefone, id: :pessoa_telefone, :size => "60"%>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label "Email: " %>
    <br><%= form.text_field :email, id: :pessoa_email, :size => "60"%>
  </div>
<% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label "Ativo: " %>
    <br><%= form.check_box :ativo, id: :aluno_ativo %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label "Matrícula" %>
    <br><%= form.text_field :matricula, id: :aluno_matricula, :size => "60"%>
  </div>
</div>  
</div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= link_to ' << Voltar', alunos_path, :class => "btn btn-danger text-white" %>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Salvar Aluno</button>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Utilizando isso eu consegui cadastrar uma pessoa e ao mesmo tempo armazenar o `ID` dessa pessoa no aluno, seria um tipo de `form_f`.

Comment: Editei sua resposta, removendo seu e-mail, caso o autor da pergunta possua mais dúvidas, deve resolve-las aqui ou abrir uma nova pergunta. Lembre-se que a dúvida dele pode ser de outros então é melhor para comunidade que a solução esteja sempre visível.

Comment: Obg Caique!    Lembrarei disso mais tarde...